# boost::filesystem get all files in the current directory - Windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, filesystems

I have a qt application which uses the following utility function to get the list of files in the given directory path.

```
void listTopLevelFiles(const boost::filesystem::path& directoryPath, std::vector<std::string> &topLevelFiles) {
    if (!exists(directoryPath))
        return;
    //non-recursive directory iterator
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_itr;
    for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator itr(directoryPath); itr != end_itr; ++itr) {
        bool selectEntry = boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(itr->status());
        if (selectEntry && (itr->path().parent_path() == directoryPath)) {
            topLevelFiles.push_back(itr->path().string());
        }
    }
}
```

However, from the metrics usage, I find that for some of the users and at certain instances, topLevelFiles vector is empty. By certain instances, I mean the following scenario

- the app works correctly by getting the top level files
- (*after some time*) reopen the app, vector size is 0 (app crashes)
- size is 0 for several reopens continuously (app crashes)
- (user does some magic - restarts the machine?!) app works - top level files get populated right.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce this in my windows machine. A point to note is that this issue does not happen for mac users of this application.

**Context of the application**: There are certain data files bundled along with the application inside the folder where the main .exe resides. These files are read using std::ifstream and copied to a string stream.

Given that the issue is transient and occurring only in Windows, I doubt the infamous file locking in windows thats causing the trouble. (Previous instance of the application left some file handles open?)

Here are some code snippets relevant to whatever happens with these data files after getting the vector from the above function

```
bool createFileStream(const std::string& filePathUTF8, std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream>& fileStream) {
    // Windows doesn't accept filenames encoded in UTF8. convert to wide string.
    std::wstring filePathW = StringUtils::getWString(filePathUTF8);
    std::ifstream* file = new std::ifstream(filePathW);
    if(file->is_open()) {
        fileStream.reset(file);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool decryptFileStream(std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream> inputFileStream, std::unique_ptr<std::istream>& outputIStream) {
    if(inputFileStream == nullptr)
        return false;
    //Get the length of the file stream
    inputFileStream->seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t length = static_cast<size_t>(inputFileStream->tellg());

    inputFileStream->seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    inputFileStream->clear();
    //Check that the file stream is in good state
    if (!inputFileStream->good())
        return false;
    //Decrypt the file stream into a stringstream
    {
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer;
        buffer.reset(new char[length]);
        //Decrypt the file stream
        int64_t readSize = decryptFileStreamFromOffset(inputFileStream.get(), length, (uint8_t *)buffer.get());
        if(readSize == length) {
            outputIStream.reset(new std::istringstream(std::string(buffer.get(), length)));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong that is a bad practice and is bound to cause issues? How should I proceed?

Comment: Just throwing a wild guess - are there any antivirus solutions installed on the target machine? Have you tried disabling Windows Defender?

Comment: Any antivirus solution must cause the problem 100% of the time right. But this issue goes away after certain tries. Also, it is a harmless little json file.

Comment: How do you know the vector is empty, and why/where does the program crash? How does the program get launched? Is there a possibility that there's a difference between runs (working directory, permissions, environment?) Is it possible that the file is being written at the same time? It looks like the program might misbehave when the file length is 0

Comment: 1\ the code loops through `topLevelFiles` vector and stores the decrypted istream in another `streamVector`. Assuming things went well, code accesses `streamVector[0]` where it crashes. 3\ It is GUI application; user double-clicks the exe; listTopLevelFiles is one of the first to be executed, so crash happens as soon as launched.4\ there is no intentional change in env between runs. 5\ No code writes to these files; it is only read from; (users can double-click the same exe multiple times causing parallel ifstream reads ONLY READS) 6\ the files should ideally never change and cannot be 0.

Comment: >> Any antivirus solution must cause the problem 100% of the time right. Not necessarily. It looks like you are encrypting/decrypting data, some AV solutions analyze  decrypted data (what if you had packed malware installed?) then calculate hash, then compare hash to known malware hash (meanwhile locking the file) if the hash has been verified already, it is cached, so no locking would occur

Comment: You need to systematically collect data on when the problem happens. 1) What OS, 2) What version of that OS. 3) What is the processor. 4) Is there any anti-virus on the System. 5) What Antivirus is running. Are your users building the app on their machine or downloading an executable? If they are building it, add 6) What is their IDE and 7) What is the compiler. 8) What version of boost are they using. You might be able to get a simulator of the OS or machine they are using it to debug. A spreadsheet, database or application like Jira will help.